# Remove the desired content from a text

Tags: vbscript

I would like to get a working code to simply remove from a text line a specific part that always begins with `"("` and finish with `")"`.

Sample text : `Hello, how are you (it is a question)`

I want to remove this part: `"(it is a question)"` to only keep this message `"Hello, how are you"`

Lost...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx);

```
input = "Hello, how are you (it is a question)"

dim re: set re = new regexp
with re
    .pattern = "\(.*\)\s?" '//anything between () and if present 1 following whitespace
    .global = true

    input = re.Replace(input, "") 
end with

msgbox input
```

Comment: I'd make the match non-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

If the part to be removed is always at the end of the string, string operations would work as well:

```
msg = "Hello, how are you (it is a question)"

pos = InStr(msg, "(")

If pos > 0 Then WScript.Echo Trim(Left(msg, pos-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sentence always ends with the ( ) section, use the split function:

```
line = "Hello, how are you (it is a question)"

splitter = split(line,"(")        'splitting the line into 2 sections, using ( as the divider
endStr = splitter(0)              'first section is index 0

MsgBox endStr                     'Hello, how are you
```

If it is in the middle of the sentence, use the split function twice:

```
line = "Hello, how are you (it is a question) and further on"

splitter = split(line,"(")
strFirst = splitter(0)             'Hello, how are you

splitter1 = split(line,")")        
strSecond = splitter1(UBound(Splitter1))    'and further on

MsgBox strFirst & strSecond        'Hello, how are you and further on
```

If there is only one instance of "( )" then you could use a '1' in place of the UBound.
Multiple instances I would split the sentence and then break down each section containing the "( )" and concatenate the final sentence.

Comment: Split is a tool to build an array from string parts separated by a single character. To use it creatively to solve a problem for which no suitable tools exists, is ok; but here are two good solutions (RegExp, InStr()), that dealt with the spurious spaces this attempt completely ignored.

Comment: I have used this successfully on numerous occasions and have had no issues with its use. Possibly this was not its intended use but it can be used so I don't understand your down vote for a working/workable solution.